# Thread.Sleep alternative in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I'm porting a library to .NET core and to maximize portability I need to eliminate the dependency on System.Threading.Thread, and therefore Thread.Sleep. Whats an alternative to this?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000)`

Comment: Most of the usual alternatives to `Thread.Sleep()` will work. See marked duplicates for examples.

Comment: If a library, one flexible aternative would be a 'delay()' callback so that the user can provide whatever mechanism is available to them.

Comment: None of the suggested questions are related to .NET Core and do not show up for searches regarding .NET Core so I do not think this is a a duplicate. Especially since the first suggestions is about windows.Forms which does not exist in .NET Core.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
you can use 

Task.Delay(2000).Wait(); // Wait 2 seconds with blocking

await Task.Delay(2000); // Wait 2 seconds without blocking
```